# Run multiple python scripts from Stata concurrently

Tags: parallel-processing, stata

Here's what I want to do:

1. Call about 8 python scripts from Stata simultaneously (to save time; if executed sequentially, they take too long). I know how to call one:

   shell "C:/Python34/python.exe" "A:/my code/Test.py"
2. Have Stata wait until they ALL finish, then do stuff within Stata.

Is it possible to call several Python scripts simultaneously?

Comment: You can winexec (rather than shell) the first k-1 and shell the kth. This will not work if the kth takes a lot less time than some of the other ones. Otherwise, take a look at -parallel- .

Comment: I think that would work well, especially because I can pick the one that takes the longest and add a wait command for a buffer. Thanks!

Comment: Another option would be to write a while loop that checks for the output of the python scripts, with a sleep command that kicks in when they don't all exists.

Comment: I tried -parallel- and it didn't work. It exited with no error, but the code clearly didn't run. I wonder if "shell" doesn't work with "parallel"? Also, do you want to write your solution as an answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have access to a Windows machine, but something like this might do the trick. Change the second part to match what you are doing with Python.

```
/* (1) Instead of Python scripts, count some files and store the counts */
winexec rm "/Users/dimitriy/*_count.txt"
winexec find /Users/dimitriy -type f -name '*.ado' | wc -l > ado_count.txt
winexec find /Users/dimitriy -type f -name '*.pdf' | wc -l > pdf_count.txt
winexec find /Users/dimitriy -type f -name '*.do'  | wc -l > do_count.txt


/* (2) Wait for ALL 3 files to be generated since Stata does not wait for winexec commands to finish */
capture ssc install fs, replace

while "`num_files'" != "3" {
    local num_files: word count `r(files)'
    sleep 10000 // sleep 10 seconds
    fs *_count.txt
}

di "All Done!"
```

---

**Response to comment below:**

That does not make sense and will not work for a whole host of reasons. I was assuming that your Python scripts spit out 8 output files. Since I don't know what they are, I tried to use 3 Mac commands that produce three files to give me something to work with in step 1. Step 2 verifies that these 3 files exist before continuing.

Assuming that each Python script i produces a file called output_i.txt for i=1,..,8, you will need to have something like this:

```
forvalues v=1/8 {
    winexec "C:/Python34/python.exe" "D:/my code/PythonCode`v'.py"
}

capture ssc install fs, replace

while "`num_files'" != "8" {
    local num_files: word count `r(files)'
    sleep 10000 // sleep 10 seconds
    fs output_*.txt
}
```

Comment: `fs` here must be installed using `ssc install fs` before the code will run.

Comment: @NickCox One day I will remember this! Thanks for catching this yet again.

Comment: A user-written command is successful if it becomes part of another user's standard repertoire. That's flattering. But it doesn't help users who don't realise where it comes from!

Comment: I thought this was working, but the do file never proceeded because the text files weren't being generated. So I must not have understood what you were saying. What I did is replace (1) with Python scripts (e.g., winexec "C:/Python34/python.exe" "D:/my code/PythonCode1.py" | wc -l > Code1_count.txt), and I thought that when those would run, the text file would be created. Could you clarify your solution?

Comment: Thank you, that makes a lot of sense! Sorry to be dense. I'm not new to Stata, but I've never used winexec before.